# jvm word size and operand stack

Tags: java, jvm

The JVM specification says that the jvm operand stack works in units of word-size, which in many implementations is the size of the native pointer - 4 bytes for 32-bit systems and 8 bytes for 64-bit systems. My question is, if the operand that is being pushed onto the stack is char (2 bytes) and the operand stack pushes and pops off operands in units of word size (8 bytes in 64-bit systems), then is that not a waste of space?

Comment: The JVM word is specified as 32 bits. It's not platform-dependent.

Comment: true, but most implementations choose size of the platform's native pointer - http://www.artima.com/insidejvm/ed2/jvm3.html

Comment: That has nothing to do with the JVM stack, which is a logical construct that does not look much like modern JIT implementations. Java words, on which Java bytecode instructions operate, are 32 bits, period. If you're asking about JVM implementations, that's a distinct issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it is "wasted space", but it simplifies the runtime immensely, plus the word sizes match the CPU they're built on, so while a waste of space, they're actually more efficient in terms of CPU processing.

And it's also just for runtime parameters, vs actual stored data.

Finally, if you look at most Java programs, the bulk of what they pass is pointers to objects, rather than scalars anyway. So it all pretty much works out in the wash.

Comment: Thanks. So all popular implementations, hotspot and openjdk, for example use this model? No way around to optimize space usage? (like memory compaction or something like that?)

Comment: you need to distinguish between a) in-memory layouts of pointers b) of primitive types c) in-cpu representation (e.g. AVX registers might be used for vectorized loops). there is no simple answer covering everything. and they're all fairly divorced from the conceptual java stack machine.

Comment: The "space usage" only happens when variables are actually loaded on the stack, not when they're stored in arrays and the like, and when variables are loaded on the stack they have to get stored in CPU registers that are based on the word size anyway.  That's not really wasting space anyway.

Answer (score 3):

"Java Virtual Machine" is an abstraction, a model describing how Java programs are executed. Actual JVM implementations like HotSpot JVM from Oracle JDK may allocate Java operand stack anywhere or nowhere at all.

E.g. in a JIT-compiled method some operands can be held in CPU registers or even treated as immediate constants rather than occupying a real stack space. Moreover, inlined methods do not have their own stack frame, they share a parent frame instead.

So, no, this is not a waste, because the specification does not prevent JVM implementations from using optimized representation. Though JVMs usually do not care: the stack space is not typically a limiting factor - the stack holds mostly a small amount of temporary values, while the actual data resides in Java Heap.